# Bash merging files

Tags: csv, awk

I will merge multiples .csv Reports.

When i download it will write like this:

File 1.

```
Name Name Flavor
AAA  BBB  CCC
AAA  BBB  CCC
```

File 2.

```
Name Name Flavor
ACB  DHB  123
```

I tried with the "awk" command.

```
awk 'FNR== 1{print ""}1' *.csv >> ReportsVol.csv
```

With them it merged all files.
But the output is then the follwing.

```
Name Name Flavor
AAA  BBB  CCC
AAA  BBB  CCC
Name Name Flavor
ACB  DHB  123
```

But i want that between each file a date is. So i think this will possible with the "timestamp" but i don't know how to deploy them. 
And the description (Name,Name,Flavor) should be just once written in the top of the file.

In the end i want something like this:

```
Name Name Flavor
 <timestamp>
AAA  BBB  CCC
ABC  BCD  CDE

<timestamp>
ACB  DHB  123
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

`systime()` will work if you use GNU awk but you would probably replace this function by the one which returns the date you need.

```
awk 'NR==1;FNR==1{print systime(); next}1' file1 file2
```

Returns

```
Name Name Flavor
1543486733
AAA  BBB  CCC
AAA  BBB  CCC
1543486733
ACB  DHB  123
```

I have no idea what kind of date you want so I used `systime()`

---

**EDIT**

Use the time of last modification of file :

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "%s", $0};FNR==1{print ""; system("date -r" FILENAME); next}1' *.csv > ReportsVol.csv
```

Returns :

```
Name Name Flavor
Thu Nov 29 11:11:49 CET 2018
AAA  BBB  CCC
AAA  BBB  CCC

Thu Nov 29 11:12:07 CET 2018
ACB  DHB  123
```

Use `system("date +%s -r " FILENAME)` if you want the date format in seconds since epoch.

Remove `print "";` if you do not need the empty line separating the files.

Comment: Error message: `awk calling undefined function systime`

Comment: Yeah sorry, what i mean, is the time where the "report" were generated so the timestamp from the file or in my case, from the different files.

Comment: It returns always `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: Maybe this one : `awk 'NR==1{printf $0};FNR==1{print ""; system("stat -f \"%m\" " FILENAME); next}1' *.csv > ReportsVol.csv`

Comment: `systime()` is gawk only so you should state that and calling `date` from `system()` like that is not guaranteed to put the date output where you expect among the awk output, you'd need `date | getline line` etc. for that approach. It's also unlikely the OP needs date called once per input file rather than just once at the start of the command. Oh, and never do `printf $0`, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead - consider the difference when $0 contains printf formatting characters like `%s`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I used systime() first as an example as I knew that OP probably didn't want systime() but didn't precise which date he wanted. But I knew that OP needed one different date per file. Thanks for the `printf "%s", $0` tip ! I edit. I'm not sure to understand this "calling date from system() like that is not guaranteed to put the date output where you expect among the awk output, you'd need date | getline line etc. for that approach", could you precise ? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you do `print 1; system("echo 2"); print 3` in awk you WILL get 1 output before 3 but when the output of `echo 2` shows up depends on buffering and possibly other issues so you can definitely get output of 1 3 2 and maybe even 2 1 3. If you want the output of a shell command to appear in a specific order within awk output then you need to capture and then print it from awk. e.g. `print 1; "echo 2" | getline x; print x; print 3` (but see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to robustly call getline).

Answer (score 1):

could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(++count==1){
     print $0 ORS systime()
  }
  if(count==2){
     print systime()
  }
  next
}
1'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v d="$(date)" 'FNR==1{print (NR==1 ? $0 : "") ORS d; next} 1' *.csv
```

Specify the `date` options as you like.

Comment: It looks good, i tried it with the ` r ` options (last modification time of file) but it not really works.. how is the correct syntax ?

Comment: last modification time of what file? Sounds like you need to update your question to explain exactly what you mean by "timestamp"?

Comment: "timestamp" is maybe the false way.. i mean specific the last modification time of each file where i merged, hope this is now more understandable